# can Spring framework use NOSQL database

Tags: database, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, nosql

can Spring framework use NOSQL database?

Is it possible to develop a spring application in which I want to use NoSQL database?

Please provide me with proper proof and example if possible.

Comment: Check the reference documentation from [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/) and [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data has multiple projects, quite a number of them are intended to be used with NoSQL databases, you may find a full list here :http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/ (both main and community modules).  Some of the notable examples are :

- Spring Data Cassandra - http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/
- Spring Data MongoDB - http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/
- Spring Data Neo4J (GraphDB) - https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/
- Spring Data DynamoDB - https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-data-dynamodb
- Spring Data ElasticSearch (search index) - http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-elasticsearch/
- ...

Comment: The link for Spring Data DynamoDB is no longer being actively supported, though it is linked from Spring's community page.  https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb is the more up-to-date fork.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at spring data mongodb:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/